# Can I split my game info into two databases when using Corona on iOS?

Tags: ios, sqlite, coronasdk

I'm creating a game using the Corona SDK that uses a SQLite db for game information, things like image file locations for different worlds and layout information for the various levels. Obviously I hope to store game progress as well (eg. high scores on levels, save current level state, which levels are unlocked, in-app-purchase data etc.)

I plan to do the following, and this where I could really use an expert opinion:

> • Deploy two SQLite databases with my app. One that has the game setup
>   data (image files, world names, etc), and one that will store the
>   player progress data. The player progress db will have a couple rows
>   prepopulated to indicate which levels are unlocked from the start.
>
> • Copy the game setup db to the Caches Directory, and copy the player
>   progress db to the Documents Directory.

Is there a better or more efficient way to do this? Corona does not support the "do not backup" flag in iOS so my cache DB has the chance of being purged due to low memory, and I will have to add extra code to check if it exists or recreate it. Also it's a bit of a pain to do SQL operations such as Joins on separate databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created apps with Corona. You may use the Documents folder to store game progress. What you should not store there is game assets and so on.
Assets and code must not be placed in a specific folder: you access them directly in the "root" folder of the app, without introducing the folder name. There you may place anything you want to use in the game that doesn't change during the use of the app.
So basically, unless you are going to do more special things, you would:

- load images, code and sqlite databases that you are not going to change by just using their name. E.g.: `local picture = display.newImageRect("mypic.png", 40, 47)`
- load and save progress data into the Documents folder: `filedata:copyFile( "scores.db", system.ResourceDirectory, "scores.db", system.DocumentsDirectory ,0)`

Where this would be the content of the `filedata:copyFile` function:

```
function filedata:copyFile( srcName, srcPath, dstName, dstPath, overwrite )

local results = true                -- assume no errors

-- Copy the source file to the destination file
--
local rfilePath = system.pathForFile( srcName, srcPath )
local wfilePath = system.pathForFile( dstName, dstPath )

local rfh = io.open( rfilePath, "rb" )              
local wfh = io.open( wfilePath, "rb" )
if wfh~=nil then
    if overwrite==0 then
        results=false
        return
    else
    end
end
--io.close(wfh)
local wfh = io.open( wfilePath, "wb" )

if  not wfh then
    results = false                 -- error
else
    -- Read the file from the Resource directory and write it to the destination directory
    local data = rfh:read( "*a" )

    if not data then
        --print( "read error!" )
        results = false     -- error
    else
        if not wfh:write( data ) then
            --print( "write error!" ) 
            results = false -- error
        end
    end
end
    -- Clean up our file handles
    rfh:close()
    wfh:close()

    return results  
end
```

And you would always access the progress database and save its contents into the Documents directory.
As you see, this is quite easier than your proposal :)